How to prove $ \tan^{-1} x < \frac{\pi}{4} + \frac{1}{2}\ln x $ as easy as you can?
How to prove $ \tan^{-1} x < \frac{\pi}{4} + \frac{1}{2}\ln x $ when $ x > 1 $ as easy as you can?
As we know,
\begin{align*}
 1 - \frac{1}{x} < \ln x < x -1
\end{align*}
when $ x > 1 $, and
\begin{align*}
  \tan^{-1} x < 2 - \frac{1}{x}
\end{align*}
But for $ tan^{-1}x $, it is not a appropriate inequality? I try give a more precise inquality about $ tan^{-1}x $ so that I can use add to prove this question?

Context and prior effort are very important when tackling questions like these. Can you provide the context in which you came across this question and, more importantly, what you've tried to do so far to prove the statement? You say you want an easy proof, so do you have an existing proof that you want to compare against? Please edit your question to provide these additional details.

What have you tried?

This is exactly the question answered here at AoPS.

@mediocrevegetable1@Dietrich Burde
Sorry, it is me who don't know the rule, And I add some.

https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/
https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions

Consider the function $f(x)=\text{lhs - rhs}$ and use derivatives

@ClaudeLeibovici Year, it is a good method to reslove this question. But I want to use inequality scaling.

If you want to use inequalities
$$\frac{\pi }{2}-\frac{1}{x}-\frac{\pi^4-8 \pi ^2-16}{16 \pi x^2}
+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)<\tan^{-1}(x) $$
$$\tan^{-1}(x)< \frac{\pi }{2}-\frac{\pi ^2-6}{4 x}+\frac{\pi ^4-12\pi ^2+18}{8 \pi
x^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)$$

The extended mean value theorem gives for $x>1$ a $\xi$ with $x> \xi >1$ with
$$\frac{\arctan x - \arctan 1}{\ln x - \ln 1} = \frac{\frac 1{1+\xi^2}}{\frac 1\xi}= \frac{\xi}{1+\xi^2}\stackrel{AM-GM}{<} \frac{\xi}{2\sqrt{\xi^2}} = \frac 12$$

This answer is gold!!!!!

It is the same as proving $$\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\text{ln}x}{2}-\text{tan}^{-1}x>0$$

Let $f(x)=\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\text{ln}x}{2}-\text{tan}^{-1}x>0$
We need to should that $f(x)>0, \quad \forall x > 1$

Taking the first derivative of $f(x)$ we get:
$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{2x}-\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$
By further simplification we get:
$$f'(x)=\frac{(x-1)^2}{2x(1+x^{2})}$$

Now, $$f'(1)=0$$
Hence, $f'(x)>0,\quad \forall x > 1$
( Which tell us $f(x)$ is increasing on the interval $(1,\infinity)$)
Therefore,$$\boxed{\tan^{-1} x < \frac{\pi}{4} + \frac{1}{2}\ln x}, \quad \boxed{\forall x > 1}$$

$f(x)=x-3$ verifies $f'(x)=1.$ So $f$ is increasing on $(1,\infty)$. However $f(2)=-1<0.$ Don't you need to use the value of $f$ at some point?
